# How to email the auto generated Email-able report of TestNG + Web driver using Java

Tags: java, email, webdriver, testng

Email-able report is generated by TestNG but don't know how can I email that report prospective stakeholders. I want to do it through script in Java using selenium web driver. If someone can help in different way then it would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an SMTP server, Instead of writing a separate code i would recommend you to integrate Selenium Webdriver with Jenkins which has an inbuilt mechanism for circulating reports to whomsoever you want.

Comment: Already tried jenkins but recieved the following error:

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\AutomationTools\Workspace\src\after_The_Fact_Functionality
No emails were triggered.
[after_The_Fact_Functionality] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\abid.ali\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson703476158448351460.bat

D:\AutomationTools\Workspace\src\after_The_Fact_Functionality>run.bat
'run.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\AutomationTools\Workspace\src\after_The_Fact_Functionality>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build